# Kubernetes V1.19.13 - kubeapi servers not able connecting to different etcd database

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have upgraded Kubernets cluster ( 3 master, 3 etcd servers database) from `1.18` to `v1.19.13` and ETCD to `3.4.13`. since than API servers are not stable, keep switching different etcd server, because of this cluster is not working properly.  these cluster running on CentOS steam 8.  This Cluster worked before the upgrade, after upgrade only I have seen this issue.

Any help to resolve this issue? Is there know issue with this version?

**API server logs**

```
I0731 00:54:39.498953       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0731 00:54:39.499025       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://0.0.0.02:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0731 00:54:39.499035       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0731 00:54:40.241615       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0731 00:54:40.241681       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://0.0.0.01:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0731 00:54:40.241691       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0731 00:54:45.348969       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0731 00:54:45.349030       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://0.0.0.03:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0731 00:54:45.349040       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0731 00:55:16.460379       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
I0731 00:55:16.460428       1 passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://0.0.0.01:2379  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
I0731 00:55:16.460439       1 clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
I0731 00:55:17.461906       1 client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
```

**etcd looks healthy**

```
# /opt/bin/etcdctl.sh   version
etcdctl version: 3.4.13
API version: 3.4

 /opt/bin/etcdctl.sh  endpoint health
127.0.0.1:2379 is healthy: successfully committed proposal: took = 9.739533ms



# /opt/bin/etcdctl.sh  check perf
 60 / 60 Boooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo! 100.00% 1m0s
PASS: Throughput is 150 writes/s
PASS: Slowest request took 0.042491s
PASS: Stddev is 0.001743s
PASS

# /opt/bin/etcdctl.sh  endpoint status --cluster -w table
+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
|          ENDPOINT          |        ID        | VERSION | DB SIZE | IS LEADER | IS LEARNER | RAFT TERM | RAFT INDEX | RAFT APPLIED INDEX | ERRORS |
+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
| https://0.0.0.02:2379 | 15cd65a732ebd5d8 |  3.4.13 |   26 MB |     false |      false |      9305 |   19813854 |           19813854 |        |
| https://0.0.0.03:2379 | add66a254676e690 |  3.4.13 |   26 MB |      true |      false |      9305 |   19813854 |           19813854 |        |
| https://0.0.0.01:2379 | e2811ed02ce71623 |  3.4.13 |   26 MB |     false |      false |      9305 |   19813854 |           19813854 |        |
+----------------------------+------------------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Please create an issue on github page: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/

Comment: @sfgroups Is your issue resolved . If yes,Please post your answer so that it would be helpful for other community members for reference.